# Bash and Sudo forking continuously, hidden fork bomb?

Tags: bash, osx, sudo, fork

I am experiencing a frustrating problem where my bash and sudo programs seem to be replicating thousands of processes on Mac. I have searched for all kinds of ways to stop them. I don't know what to do. I have restarted the computer. They self replicate after: pkill -f bash

I don't want to have a looped kill script battling this ongoing. I just want it to stop. Thank you so much.

The only thing I can think that I did was try to run openvpn accidentally on the wrong file type. It then gave me, fork: resource temporarily unavailable.

[image]

Comment: You would have to run the `pkill` with `sudo` to be able to kill a `bash` process belonging to root.  If you also posted your script, we could possibly tell more about what's going on.

Comment: I did do that, the script that is causing it is unknown. It regenerates processes

Comment: `pgrep -lf bash` and `pgrep -lf sudo` should give you more of a hint by showing the command line of the processes.

Comment: Ya, so that revealed that for whatever reason my command: sudo openvpn —config id_rsa.dms is causing a problem. Literally 100% cpu is used up. The id_rsa is a wrong file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have diagnosed that the offending command is in fact your `openvpn` invocation.

You should be able to kill `openvpn` by using

```
sudo pkill -f openvpn
```

Failing that, temporarily uninstalling `openvpn` or just changing the executable's name should cause it to stop respawning, at least after a reboot (I'm a bit unclear on why a reboot did not stop this in the first instance).

If it does not respond to the termination signal, you could, as a last resort, use the kill signal,

```
sudo pkill -KILL -f openvpn
```

Comment: Killing didn't work, but brew uninstall openvpn did! Thank you